# What tools and/or stack options do I have for an automated underwriting engine?

Tags: algorithms, recommendation-engine

I'm about to embark on a project which will involve receiving a high-volume of financial securities (example: real estate "notes") via a high-speed data feed / api and applying a one or more pre-defined models with a set of underwriting rules in order to rank those securities in terms of risk.

In some cases, we may want to apply different statistical models we've already pre-defined and return the rating as fast as possible. Another use case if we would want to give users the ability to analyze notes by taking an existing model and tweaking different variables to see how that might influence the overall risk rating.

Are there any pre-packaged SAAS applications that can do this and/or if we were to go and build a custom solution, what stack / set of technologies would you do it in?

Comment: What protocol(s) do you need to use? Or do you have the choice to impose any protocol you want?